# Separate building layer into buildings within villages and remote buildings using QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, density

I'm trying to separate a building layer into two layers. One layer should show the buildings within villages, and the other one the remote buildings.

My first approach was to buffer the buildings (and dissolve) so I can separate it by the area of the buffer areas. Big areas are villages, small ones are the remote buildings. It failed because the dissolve function did dissolve the attributes too.

The second approach was to create a grid and change the polygons of the buildings with a point layer so I can count the points inside a cell of the grid. Unfortunately I could not find a function that works (I'm a beginner with GIS software). Do any of you have an idea how I can solve this task?

Comment: You could use `DBSCAN clustering`, but you'll have to experiment a lot with the values. In the end all buildings in villages will be in a cluster, all other not.

Comment: Works great, thanks.